# Flutter/Dart: Convert a Double to a Duration?

Tags: flutter, dart, time, type-conversion, duration

I have a double which is a number of milliseconds that I need to convert to a Duration in Flutter. How can I convert milliseconds to Duration?

```
Duration _myduration = mymilliseconds_as_a_double(how to convert?) ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be `Duration(microseconds: (millis * 1000).toInt());` if you want to use the fractional part of the millisecond double as well.

Microseconds is the highest precision, the fraction of microseconds you lose here would have to be lost either way.